# What does this mean? Second order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation

$y" + qy' + py = e^{ax}$

I need to find the complete solution for all a's. I've calculated the solutions for the homogenous differential equation, just not sure what my next move is.

What's the general method?

Comment: You should post your solution so we can help you from there

Comment: I think that's too much to explain in one single post. Here is a suggestion for you to read: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IntroSecondOrder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'll mention one trick in an attempt to be helpful.

Make a guess that $y = A e^{B x}$. Plug this into the differential equation and see by inspection what $A$ and $B$ must be to make it work out right.